# How do I transform a simulink simulation into a script?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, simulink

Here is my problem. I have an algorithm (.m file) that communicates with a simulink simulation. The problem is that simulink takes to long to run and I need it to run each script iteration. So I´d like to make it faster by tranforming my simulation into a script (.m file). Is it possible? What would be another solution for this problem? 
Thank you

Comment: No, it's not possible. I suggest you try and work out what's causing your simulation to run slowly (solver settings, step size, etc...) and try to improve that. Maybe the "communication" between the MATLAB script and the Simulink model is the bottleneck?

Comment: Thanks I´ll figure it out how to make my simulation faster.

Comment: See http://uk.mathworks.com/videos/speeding-up-simulink-applications-81795.html and http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94052-how-can-i-speed-up-simulation-of-my-simulink-model.